# Benefits of migrate a clipper application running on Netware/ipx to Windows server 2003/IP

Tags: ads, clipper

Anyone knows if there are benefits migrating from netware IPX to Server 2003/IP ?
I´m running a legacy clipper application and I want to add php or java applications.

the actual: environment is:
Novel Netware 6 -
IPX -
ADS 6

I´m thinking to migrate to :
Server 2003 -
ADS 10 -
IP
USE OF ADSDOSIP

Answer (score 3):

For a start, Clipper compiled apps may not run at all being 16 bit applications. If you want to keep your code as predominantly Clipperesque, then either [Harbour](http://www.harbour-project.org/) or [xHarbour](http://www.xharbour.org/) are your best bet. Both of these are 32bit Windows development tools.

Answer (score 1):

Migrate to Linux using Harbour! 
http://www.harbour-project.org
I use it. I doubt anything else will compare to Harbour running on Linux :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of solid technical reasons to make this change, but the very practical reason is that IPX isn't very well supported anymore.